# Why UITableView reloadData can not in animate block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

Before, I don't know why, when I `reloadData` my tableVIew, it takes a very long time.

[image]

I have test `Log` to prove, shows the slow is not because the network:

```
2016-12-29 14:50:20.958 Eee[1572:25220] lml-info-vc-test-net-began
2016-12-29 14:50:20.958 Eee[1572:25220] lml-info-vc-test-net-end
2016-12-29 14:50:20.972 Eee[1572:25220] lml-info-vc-test-net-animations-reloadData-bigin
2016-12-29 14:50:34.870 Eee[1572:25220] lml-info-vc-test-net-animations-reloadData-end
```

As we see, the **net-began** and **net-end** takes very little time.
But the **reloadData-bigin** and **reloadData-end** takes a long time, so I searched the SO, what did the `reloadData` do? I want to know deeply, not simple answer, I searched always is simple answer, not analyse in depth.

My `reloadData` code:

```
//[self.pre_tableView reloadData];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{

     NSLog(@"lml-info-vc-test-net-animations-reloadData-bigin");

     [self.pre_tableView reloadData];
     NSLog(@"lml-info-vc-test-net-animations-reloadData-end");
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     //Do something after that...
     [_pre_tableView.mj_footer endRefreshing];
     [_pre_tableView.mj_header endRefreshing];

 }];
```

I use animation block, and in the `completionHadler` to end the refreshing.

I also searched the apple [docs for reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata?language=objc)

In the Discussion:

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates.

**Attention**

With the attentive sentence:

> It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block

Well! It means I should not in my `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration` method to `reloadData`, so I replace my code to below:

```
[self.pre_tableView reloadData];
[_pre_tableView.mj_footer endRefreshing];
[_pre_tableView.mj_header endRefreshing];
```

Now it is not slow any more. Very happy, I find the reason.

But, I just want to know why, why can not put `reloadData` method in animation block ?

And it `reloadData` did not fail, even takes a long time, in the animate block happens what? then it takes so many time here?

---

**Edit -1**

My additional code is below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.pre_dataSource.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:info_TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[LMLAgricultureTechCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:info_TableIdentifier];
    }
    //NSLog(@"lml-info-vc-test-cellSetModel-began");
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).model = self.pre_dataSource[indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"lml-info-vc-test-cellSetModel-end");
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).indexPath = indexPath;
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).delegate = self;
    ((LMLAgricultureTechCell *)cell).photo_view.delegate = self;

    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> * cell自适应 * >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    id model;

    model = self.pre_dataSource[indexPath.row];

    return [self.pre_tableView cellHeightForIndexPath:indexPath model:model keyPath:@"model" cellClass:[LMLAgricultureTechCell class] contentViewWidth:[self cellContentViewWith]];
}
```

Comment: animation block is use for creating animation, why would you put reload data there? Probably the slowness is because it's trying to animate everything while re-rendering cell?

Comment: @Tj3n, Though the apple's doc, I know I can not put `reloadData` in the animation block, but why, the docs did not explain more.

Comment: Please show your methods of UITableViewDataSource and ... Delegate. Especially cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You know you cannot put reloadData in animation block by doc, so obey it.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView.animateWithDuration...` methods can only animate values that are `animatable`. Although it sometimes feels like magic - it's not really...
`reloadData` is an async method that can not be handled by the `animate` block the be animated.

If you want to animate the transition you can either use `insert/delete/moveRows` or use the [`transitionWithView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622574-transitionwithview) method of `UIView`. This method would render the view off-screen completely as it will look after all the changes you put in it's block, than animate transit between the current state of the view and the newly rendered view. The animation itself depends on the options you deliver, and you probably want to use `UIViewAnimationOptionsTransitionCrossDissolve`.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.pre_tableView 
              duration:0.3 
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionsTransitionCrossDissolve 
            animations: ^{ 
                [self.pre_tableView reloadData];
            } completion: ^(BOOL finished) { 
                ... 
            }];
```

Comment: Cross, as you say, "reloadData is an async method that can not be handled by the animate block the be animated", but it is reloaded even takes a long time, it reload success, but takes a long time.why takes a long time? rather than failed.